# Change origin? Win32?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gdi, win32gui

is it possible to move the origin on the display from top left to the centre of the display?

Why I want to do this? So that, I can plot points such as:

`(-21,-25),(22,-25),(21,25),(-21,25)`

As you can see that some of these are negative and hence not visible on the display. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the GDI function `SetViewportOrgEx()`. Note that in GDI, the coordinates are not relative to the screen; they're relative to the device context, which typically corresponds to your window's client area.

Comment: Will do, But there is a time limit on it :P

Comment: Not all questions admit one, unfortunately :)